EntityManagerFactory to Plan SQL
I am using Intellij -->Tools -->Persistence and able to execute "Run Query in JPA Console" (Already DB is connected). And able to generate the output which has many joins.
Could anyone tell me how i can generate the query which returned me the above output ?
As stated above i am now seeing just the output after all the joins.
